# Is there an odd function $g$ over the reals such that $g(0)\ne0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, real-numbers, symmetry

Is there an odd function $g$ on domain $\mathbb{R}$, where $g(0)$ isn't equal to $0$ ?

Comment: Odd function means $f(-x)=-f(x)\,$. For $x=0$ that means $f(0)=-f(0)\,$.

Comment: Convince yourself by substituting $x=0$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions).

Comment: Answer: It would be odd...

Answer (score 6):

Hint. Note that if $g$ is odd and it is defined at $0$ then $g(0)=-g(-0)=-g(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Any odd function on $\Bbb R$ is a symmetric curve about the origin...and if $g(0)$ is not equal to zero,then $0$ must have to two images..and that will contradict the statement of a function.....so answer is NOT.